# Tinymce Richtext-editor not rendering macro RTE

Tags: macros, tinymce, umbraco, rich-text-editor, rte

I'm running a site with umbraco version 4.11.1 and is trying to render the info of a macro within a tinyMCE richtext-editor without any success.

In version 4.11.1 (and perhaps some other versions before this) Umbraco has a button for rendering macros within tinyMCE. If you click this button it will show all the macros that you have been able to render. If I add a macro, it will render out the stuff I've entered in the macro, within an orange-dotted border, which means that the editor understands that I've added the macro.

However, after I save and publish and enter the page where I've added the macro, it doesn't render anything. I came across some posts when I googled the problem and found out that I could trace the problem using a querystring (?umbDebugShowTrace=true) and look through the HTML and see what has been rendered. I found the following HTML:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="Testmacro" />
```

...which should render, if you ask the people in these posts.

If anyone had this problem, or know how to solve it. Please feel free to participate.

Thanks in advance.
David

Comment: How are you rendering out the TinyMCE property? Can you show us your (I'm assuming) razor code?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 string macro = umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"Testmacro\" ReusableText=\"1112\" ></?UMBRACO_MACRO>", 1112);

 string result = paragraph.Replace("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"Testmacro\" ReusableText=\"1112\" />",macro);
```

Best regrads